# Data Type different from reference table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle18c

I am creating a sample [IRTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Railway_Catering_and_Tourism_Corporation) database that includes tables `ticket` and `train_ticket_fare`. I created a table `ticket` with a column as 
`ticket_class varchar(6)`. 
In the table `train_ticket_fare`, I referenced it using this 
`ticket_class references ticket`.

I re-created the tables to check but couldn't find the error.

```
SQL> desc ticket
 Name                    Null?    Type
----------------------- -------- ----------------
 PNR_NO                  NOT NULL NUMBER(10) 
 TRANSACTIONID                    NUMBER(10)
 FROM_STATION                     VARCHAR2(20)
 TO_STATION                       VARCHAR2(20)
 DATE_OF_JOURNEY                  DATE
 TICKET_CLASS                     VARCHAR2(6) //this
 DATE_OF_BOOKING                  DATE
 TICKET_FARE                      NUMBER(8,2)
 TRAIN_NUMBER                     NUMBER(5)

SQL> create table Train_Ticket_fare
  2    (
  3      train_number        references train,
  4      ticket_class        references ticket, //this
  5      base_fare           number(7,2),
  6      reservation_charge  number(6,2),
  7      superfast_charge    number(6,2),
  8      other_charge        number(6,2),
  9      tatkal_charge       number(6,2),
 10      service_tax         number(6,2),
 11      primary key(train_number, ticket_class)
 12    );

Table created.

SQL> desc Train_Ticket_fare
 Name                    Null?    Type
 ----------------------- -------- ----------------
 TRAIN_NUMBER            NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 TICKET_CLASS            NOT NULL NUMBER(10)  //this
 BASE_FARE                        NUMBER(7,2)
 RESERVATION_CHARGE               NUMBER(6,2)
 SUPERFAST_CHARGE                 NUMBER(6,2)
 OTHER_CHARGE                     NUMBER(6,2)
 TATKAL_CHARGE                    NUMBER(6,2)
 SERVICE_TAX                      NUMBER(6,2)
```

Resolved! Thanks @stickybit. The table `Train_ticket_fare` must have `TICKET_CLASS` as primary key which is to be referenced to the table `Ticket`. I did the opposite and referenced it wrong.

Comment: `ticket_class` isn't the primary key of `ticket`, is it? I guess `pnr_no` is? So the data type of the foreign key referencing `ticket` it the one of the primary key of `ticket`. If you want to be able to reference ticket classes you have to make a table for them and reference that.

Comment: ticket_class VARCHAR2(6) REFERENCES ticket(ticket_class )

declare like this in the Train_Ticket_fare table

Comment: @stickybit Yes, Thanks got it. Totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was due to referencing.
The table Train_ticket_fare must have TICKET_CLASS as primary key which is to be referenced to the table Ticket. I did the opposite and referenced it wrong.
That is why it was showing wrong data-type.
Thanks @stickybit
Sorry if I posted wrong question. I am new to platform.

Answer (score 0):

The `foreign key` in the child table will generally reference a `primary key` in the parent table.

In your case, I am assuming that `TICKET_CLASS` is the `primary key` of the table `TRAIN`.

You can change the `primary key` and `foreign key` according to your business logic. Following is just an example based on an assumption:

```
CREATE TABLE TICKET (
    PNR_NO            NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    TRANSACTIONID     NUMBER(10),
    FROM_STATION      VARCHAR2(20),
    TO_STATION        VARCHAR2(20),
    DATE_OF_JOURNEY   DATE,
    TICKET_CLASS      VARCHAR2(6),
    DATE_OF_BOOKING   DATE,
    TICKET_FARE       NUMBER(8, 2),
    TRAIN_NUMBER      NUMBER(5),
    CONSTRAINT TICKET_PK PRIMARY KEY ( TICKET_CLASS )
);

CREATE TABLE TRAIN_TICKET_FARE (
    TRAIN_NUMBER         NUMBER(10)
        REFERENCES TRAIN ( TRAIN_NUMBER ), 
       -- DATA TYPE MUST BE SAME AS TRAIN_NUMBER OF TABLE TRAIN
    TICKET_CLASS         VARCHAR2(6)
        REFERENCES TICKET ( TICKET_CLASS ),  
       -- ASSUMING THAT ticket_class IS PRIMARY KEY OF TABLE ticket_class 
    BASE_FARE            NUMBER(7, 2),
    RESERVATION_CHARGE   NUMBER(6, 2),
    SUPERFAST_CHARGE     NUMBER(6, 2),
    OTHER_CHARGE         NUMBER(6, 2),
    TATKAL_CHARGE        NUMBER(6, 2),
    SERVICE_TAX          NUMBER(6, 2),
    PRIMARY KEY ( TRAIN_NUMBER,
                  TICKET_CLASS )
       -- below is the another way of defining the foreign key
       --CONSTRAINT Train_Ticket_fare_FK FOREIGN KEY (ticket_class) REFERENCES ticket(TICKET_CLASS)
);
```

Table's column must be defined with its own data type and it should be referenced using foreign key constraint as shown in the example. (not like this `ticket_class        references ticket`)

I hope you will be able to find the direction.

Refer to this [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php) for more information on Foreign key.

Cheers!!

Comment: Not entirely true (sentence about the way of how foreign key is supposed to reference a master table). These two statements are perfectly OK: `create table train (train_number number primary key);` `create table ticket (train_number number references train);`

Comment: I have given just an example as few things are an assumption as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you wanted something like this:

```
create table train
( train_number        number(5) constraint train_pk primary key
);

create table ticket_class
( ticket_class        varchar2(6) constraint ticket_class_pk primary key
);

create table ticket
( pnr_no              number(10)  constraint ticket_pk primary key
, transactionid       number(10)
, from_station        varchar2(20)
, to_station          varchar2(20)
, date_of_journey     date
, ticket_class        references ticket_class
, date_of_booking     date
, ticket_fare         number(8,2)
, train_number        number(5)
);

create table train_ticket_fare
( train_number        references train
, ticket_class        references ticket_class
, base_fare           number(7,2)
, reservation_charge  number(6,2)
, superfast_charge    number(6,2)
, other_charge        number(6,2)
, tatkal_charge       number(6,2)
, service_tax         number(6,2)
, constraint train_ticket_fare primary key (train_number, ticket_class)
);

SQL> @desc train_ticket_fare
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 TRAIN_NUMBER                              NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 TICKET_CLASS                              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6)
 BASE_FARE                                          NUMBER(7,2)
 RESERVATION_CHARGE                                 NUMBER(6,2)
 SUPERFAST_CHARGE                                   NUMBER(6,2)
 OTHER_CHARGE                                       NUMBER(6,2)
 TATKAL_CHARGE                                      NUMBER(6,2)
 SERVICE_TAX                                        NUMBER(6,2)
```

It's not good having a table and a column (TICKET_CLASS) with the same name. It works, but it might lead to ambiguity and confusion. One way to avoid this is to name tables using the plural e.g. TRAINS, TICKET_CLASSES, TICKETS.